# Ошибка бота: Отсутствуют разрешения

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Бот перестал работать после изменения прав канала, хотя даже попытки все вернуть как было не дали результатов.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils
from discord.utils import get


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
descp = [' - записаться как участник \n - присоединиться к лобби']
post_ID = None


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('бот запущен')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def lobby(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Открыт набор в игру!',
                        description=''.join(descp),
                        colour=discord.Color.red()
                        )
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await message.add_reaction('')
    await message.add_reaction('')
    global post_ID
    post_ID = message.id
    
    print('> создано лобби ID =', post_ID)
```

Мне выдает ошибку об отсутствующих разрешениях, но я не могу понять какие именно надо боту выдать разрешения (казалось у него есть то, что надо)

```
бот запущен
Ignoring exception in command lobby:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "", line 23, in lobby
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
  File "", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Мне что-то надо обновить или как решить данную задачу?
Что я пробовал:

- редактировать права канала
- редактировать права роли бота
- переустанавливать бота

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем и целом, чтобы решить проблему именно с разрешениями, я просто создал новый сервер и больше внимания уделил правам на каналах и ролях.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит попробовать создай для бота отдельную роль с его именем, и поставь для неё разрешение "администратор", в самом низу списка прав.
Или же, если это не помогает - пригласи бота на сервер по новой, но только с правами администратора:

```
https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=908404770690175067&permissions=8&scope=bot%20applications.commands
```

В ссылке, в значение "client_id=" поставь айди своего бота, с сайта discord devs, а в значение "permissions" должна быть цифра 8.